# can a convolutional neural network be reverse engineered?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reverse-engineering, privacy

can a modern,complex convolutional neural network for object detection be reverse engineered to acquire the original image training data? Thanks.

i did try searching for my question online but the answers didn't exactly answer my question

Comment: So essentially you are asking if, simplified to linear regression, one could reconstruct the point cloud of given data from the regression line? Only that the input space is now much very much higher dimensional, the data cloud clustered around some very low-dimensional subset, and the regression function much more unpredictable outside this point cloud. So what you are demanding is essentially [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMIHNiR3CP8) and lots of other "zoom, enhance, cornea reflection" phantasies.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the video was hilarious,so you are saying; reconstructing every training sample just by reverse engineering a model isn't plausible

Comment: GAN exist, so if the output of the given network can be evaluated into a decision if the input was realistic or garbage, one could train a generator to produce images that might possibly look like the training data. That would correspond to a function that approximates a map from some cube to the above-mentioned low-dimensional surface. However, it seems more impossible to limit the extend of the range of the generator correctly, so the results could also deviate into the hilarious or disturbing, or just incomprehensible.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so in order to do that there is huge "guesswork" involved?

Comment: "gradcam", "deepdream", "overfitting", "generalizing"...

Answer (score 0):

Yes,of course. When you add different filteration techniques like average pooling, max pooling, the spatial dimension of your image will obviously decrease until the Same padding is set. This techniques is known as **downsampling**. So to aquire or preserve the original size, there are different **Upsampling** techniques. These are some common Upsampling techniques:

**1. Nearest neighbor**: It is a simple upsampling techniques. Related or common data in rows and column are copied near to them until original size meets.

**2. Unpooling**: This techniques reverse the every techniques that was used during downsampling. It is unpooling the pooling layer that we have applied before. It would not guarantee exact same pixel but approximate resolutin can be obtain.

**3. Transpose convolution**: So you know, convolution layer was multiplied with pooling layer and the image lost its dimension. What Transpose convolution does is it transpose what happen during regular convolution operation also known as deconvolution. It performs the opposite operation of regular convolution, allowing the network to learn to increase the resolution of the feature maps.

If you required additional information I recommend you to go through it. [Downsampling and Upsampling in CNN](https://iq.opengenus.org/downsampling-and-upsampling-in-cnn/)

Comment: so let's say the model was trained with 100k images with many objects,these techniques you mentioned can reverse the model and reconstruct each and every image in the training dataset?

Comment: If model is already trained, It will depend on what kind of architecture it has and still it is difficult to retrieve exact same pixel, some approximate/near to original image could be constructed.